# How to catch email from local app server. Nodejs

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I have lite nodejs server. I am trying to implement password reset flow. I use nodemailer to send email with reset password link. I want to test if I send email properly. I don't want to use any remote smpt.

**What I can use on my local environment to catch emails and check if they are good?**

Comment: do you looking for something like: `mailcatcher`?

Comment: yes, I think it is what i need. Thanks @Evo

Answer (score 2):

I used  [mailcatcher](https://mailcatcher.me/). It is a super simple SMTP server which catches any message sent to it to display in a web interface.

I have following configuration:

```
let smtpConfig = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 1025,
  secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
  auth: {
    user: 'user',
    pass: 'password'
  }
 };
```

**Do not forget to add user and password in auth section. It can be even white space. But it can't be empty string in this case you'll get error.**

```
const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);
```

And now you can see all sent emails here  http://127.0.0.1:1080

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```